# linker error in xcode on sample hybrid project build

Tags: mobile, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk, xcode

I've tried building 2 of the sample projects into xcode generated via 'forceios create samples'. They both have 5 errors when I try to build the project.

Here's an example of one:

```
Apple Mach-O Linker Error "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SFKeyStoreManager", referenced from:

objc-class-ref in libSalesforceOAuth.a(SFOAuthCredentials.o)
```

It then has several very similiar errors for `SFPasscodeManager`, `SFSDKCryptoUtils`, `_kSFPassCodeProviderPBKDF2`, and the last is `Linker command failed with exit code 1`.

Any suggestions on how to fix this? I've tried removing and re-adding the www folder as suggested in a read.me file.

I've also noticed theres are 3 red files under SalesforceSDKCore, I'm guessing its looking for these but not finding them? `SFAccountManager.h`, `SFPasscodeManager.h`, and `SFPasscodeProviderManager.h`. I don't see these in the actual directories outside of xcode.